# Google Analytics report is showing URL parameters that look like session ids

Tags: google-analytics, url

I am noticing some weird URLs in the Google Analytics content report. The parameters in the urls appears similar to php session ids (not sure though). Just want to make sure it is not something that is caused by any misconfiguartion or such on the site, as the urls doesn't make any sense and the normals urls on the site are quite different. Here are examples of the urls

```
/index.php?____pgfa=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5hcHBhbmNlLmNvbS8=&s=tshirt

/index.php?q=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5hcHBhbmNlLmNvbS9jYXRlZ29yeS9hbmRyb2lkL2Rlc2lnbi92aWV3cy8=
```

If there was one or two entries like this I would have normally ignored, but I am seeing too many entries like this to be a bit concerned. What is the reason behind this? Thanks.

Comment: That's kinda odd! I would need to see more of your log file to know if there is any funny business here. It is not uncommon that various software is used to landscape (at least) your site to see what software you are using and to see what vulnerabilities exist. It is not uncommon that some of these will spider your site, then try and use various parameters according what the spider sees. There would be a normal pattern of use that looks like a spider then modified parameters and other kinds of odd accesses that can span several days or weeks. Hopefully, this is not what is happening here.

Comment: I haven't seen this on my own sites.   It would be most helpful to find what the referrer URLs to these pages are.   Unfortunately, Google Analytics won't tell you that.   You would have to consult your access logs.   It is also possible that Google Webmaster Tools could tell you the referrers if Googlebot has found and crawled any of them.